# Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview, binding

I am trying to bind a `List(Of Customer)` data object to a Listview. This listview uses a custom control to display the values. The problem is that no data is being displayed by the custom control and my output shows this error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is
> not valid for target property.; Value='WPF_Controls.OrderItem'
> BindingExpression:Path=; DataItem='OrderItem' (Name=''); target
> element is 'OrderItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Customer' (type
> 'Customer')

I looked up this error and it seems to be a conversion error. The application expects a different datatype. What I don't understand is why it expects a different datatype. Let me show you the code.

The customer class:

```
Public Class Customer
    Property Name As String
    Property Address As String
End Class
```

The XAML for the listview:

```
<UserControl x:Name="userControl" x:Class="OrderListview"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:OrderItem Customer="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Codebehind for the listview:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class OrderListview
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    
    Private _Customers As New List(Of Customer)
    
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.DataContext = Me
    End Sub

    Public Property Customers As List(Of Customer)
        Get
            Return _Customers
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Customer))
            _Customers = value
            DoPropertyChanged("Customers")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Sub DoPropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
        Dim e As New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The XAML for the user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="OrderItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="112.5" Width="632.717">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding Customer.Name}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Codebehind for the user control:

```
Public Class OrderItem

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.DataContext = Me
    End Sub

    Public Shared ReadOnly CustomerProperty As DependencyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Customer",
        GetType(Customer),
        GetType(OrderItem),
        New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing))

    Public Property Customer As Customer
        Get
            Return DirectCast(GetValue(CustomerProperty), Customer)
        End Get
        Set(value As Customer)
            SetValue(CustomerProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

As you can see in the listview XAML is that the `ItemSource` is bound to the `Customers` property. That works because when I replace the user control with a simple label it shows my data. I created a user control with a `Customer` `DependencyProperty` so that I could pass the customers into the user control. The label inside the user control binds to `Customer.Name` and the `DataContext` is set to the control itself so the `Customer` property should be visible. No errors are given so the paths seem to be correct.

So why the error? The `List(Of Customer)` itemsource produces the correct datatype for `Customer` in my opinion.

Comment: Remove `Me.DataContext = Me` from the UserControl's constructor, and bind in its XAML like `<Label Content="{Binding Customer.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />`

Comment: @Clemens Thank you! Post that as an answer for the points. (I see my question has been closed, thanks anyway)